# Extending import system for dynamic module

Tags: python, python-import

I'm working on a project that dynamically collects classes from another module and creates new classes based off the ones it found. For example, if the source module has a "AdaptiveFilter" class, a new class called "AdaptiveFilterNode" is created that contains an "AdaptiveFilter" instance. I've been adding these generated classes to a dynamically created module (`module_from_spec()`) and created a `MetaPathFinder` and `Loader` to extend the `import` system. This works perfectly fine when importing the dynamic module, e.g. `import nodes.auto_gen` or `from nodes.auto_gen import AdaptiveFilterNode`, but fails when trying to directly import a class, e.g. `import nodes.auto_gen.AdaptiveFilterNode`. I need to be able to directly import a class because the generated classes need to be pickleable, which requires a direct import. I believe the problem is in the Finder that I made:

```
class MyNodeFinder(MetaPathFinder):

    def find_spec(self, fullname, path=None, target=None):

        if fullname == 'nodes.auto_gen':
            auto_gen_spec = = ModuleSpec('nodes.auto_gen',
                                           MyLoader())

            return auto_gen_spec
        return None
```

From my limited understanding on the import system, there's nothing in the finder or the module spec that tells the import system there's classes contained in the `nodes.auto_gen` module until the module is already loaded. How can I create a finder/loader that replicates the standard import system for a dynamic module with dynamic classes?

**EDIT**: Full example, module "dynamic_creator":

dynamic_creator/__init__.py

```
from importlib.machinery import ModuleSpec
from importlib.util import module_from_spec
import sys
from importlib.abc import MetaPathFinder
from importlib.abc import Loader


__version__ = '0.0.0'


class _MyWrapperClass():

    wrapped_func = None

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.wrapped_func(*args, **kwargs)


class MyFinder(MetaPathFinder):

    def find_spec(self, fullname, path=None, target=None):

        if fullname == 'dynamic_creator.auto_gen':
            auto_node_spec = ModuleSpec('dynamic_creator.auto_gen',
                                        MyLoader())

            return auto_node_spec
        return None


class MyLoader(Loader):

    def create_module(self, spec):
        return module_from_spec(ModuleSpec('dynamic_creator.auto_gen', None))

    def exec_module(self, module):
        def create_type(func):
            t = type(func.__name__, (_MyWrapperClass, ), {})
            t.wrapped_func = func

            # Wait, you can do this?
            t.__module__ = 'dynamic_creator.auto_gen'
            return t

        funcs_to_wrap = [
            sum,
            abs,
            pow
        ]

        for func in funcs_to_wrap:
            setattr(module, func.__name__, create_type(func))


my_finder = MyFinder()

sys.meta_path.append(my_finder)
```

Test script:

```
import dynamic_creator.auto_gen  # Works
from dynamic_creator.auto_gen import abs  # Works
import dynamic_creator.auto_gen.pow as my_pow  # Fails
```

**EDIT**: The reported error is as follows:

`No module named 'dynamic_creator.auto_gen.pow'; 'dynamic_creator.auto_gen' is not a package`

Comment: Could you provide a complete code example which works for `from ... import ...` but fails when doing `import ...`?

Comment: Added and example of a simple module "dynamic_creator" with the dynamic module "dynamic_creator.auto_gen". The example is trivialized just to demonstrate the problem

Comment: What if you do `if fullname.startswith(...` instead of `if fullname ==`

Comment: Also, (a) please post the complete error, and (b) step through in a debugger (or add print statements) so you can see (i) where it falls and (ii) why.

Comment: `startswith()` was my first thought as well, but that doesn't solve the problem. The error is: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dynamic_creator.auto_gen.pow'; 'dynamic_creator.auto_gen' is not a package`

Comment: I'm not sure I can step into the `import` mechanism, my attempts at placing breakpoints in the files indicated by the call stack have been unsuccessful.